# Security on Ubuntu 12.04 LST Server for Business App

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing bussines application based on php and mysql on ubuntu 12.04 lts server.
I have closed all ports except :80 and php code can be executed only by security login and not using cookies but session.

What other vulnerability can server have and what security precaution i need to take for hight security???

Comment: Ditching php might be one.

Comment: @LucasKauffman Thank you for your replay, but I am more interested in servers security. what can I do beside disabling ports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all:

- create a user to run your PHP code as who has no more user rights than needed, including being jailed within his user context
- configure [suphp](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html)
- get a hardening guide for ubuntu and follow it thoroughly
- configure [apparmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor)
- limit user access and have a remote logging tool set up
- implement [auditd](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/01/a-brief-introduction-to-auditd/) for sensitive folders
- set up SSL with a valid certificate (443) if your app handles sensitive information

For MySQL preferably you have a table to which you can only add records. Every record has a field "deleted, to which your user mysql application user can have access. This record can be set to True or False. Your user can insert rows but cannot delete any, he can also only update those fields within a record which should be updated. Deleting can be done by setting True or False (your application needs to account for this).

Use as much stored procedures as possible, off-load as much database logic to your database as you can.

Configure a WebApplication firewall and [HIDS](http://www.ossec.net/).

Comment: Thank you again, i will do all of this. i dont use remote logging to server. The only remote access is :80 php pages.

Comment: If you've got "security login" to port 80 then implementing SSL on port 443 and using that instead should be one of your steps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hard your system you can also fail2ban. It's a script that watch log files and set blocking rules to the firewall in case of illegal access.

I use it to monitoring and block the access to not available websites and the ssh login trails.

It's easy to configure, without attracting attention and works fine :-)